# Not able to connect to thrift server from spark shell

Tags: apache-spark, spark-thriftserver

I am trying to connect to spark thrift server via spark shell by using following command:

```
val df = spark
    .read
    .option("url", "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000")
    .option("dbtable", "people")
    .format("jdbc")
    .load
```

> error: not found: value spark

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

What message do you get when you type spark into the shell? make sure you have a valid spark session.

res1: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@2bc0b8c8

is what you should see, if you don't see that in the spark-shell then you likely didn't start the shell correctly.

Comment: If you have a question for the author of the question please put that in the comments. When answering please provide instructions on how to solve the problem.

Comment: I can't comment yet StackOverflow won't let me.

Comment: Then accrue enough reputation to leave comments.